# how to get pass firewall with google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firewall

Here's a question for the creators of google maps:

I heard that google maps api is being blocked by most secured network and given that there are many servers that hosts google maps, unblocking all of these would be difficult but not impossible.

So question lies is, how often does these map database server change? We would need to unblock them everytime they do which some people claim to be 6 months or so.

Is there a more stable solution to get past this?

Currently my website is only available for users are who registered members and we are about to add in the firewall for security. We understand that google maps will be affected by this change so we would like to know the solution before we implement it.

Also, if there is no solution to the problem with the current google maps API, does signing up for google map api for businesses help to overcome this? and how?

Answer (score 0):

**Note: You must be using Google Maps for Work (paid) in order to host maps on a website that is behind a firewall. Otherwise you are in breach of the terms of service.**

Note: You may need to be using Google Maps for Work (paid) in order to host maps on a website that is only available for registered members. Otherwise you may be in breach of the terms of service.

As for configuring your firewall, Google will provide you with all of the settings that are needed. You don't need to make constant changes to keep it working.

The primary source of information for configuring your firewall is found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/prelaunch_checklist#firewall

**Configure Firewall to Allow Access to the Google Maps API Services**

**Why it's important:** The Maps API services use a variety of domains, some which do not belong to the *google.com domain. If you are behind a restrictive firewall, it is important you understand which Maps API services use which domains.

Failure to allow access to the correct domains will cause API requests to fail, which can break your applications. For a complete listing of domains used by the Maps APIs, please consult our [portal resource](http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal) (login required):

Log in to the [Google Enterprise Support Portal](http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal)
The support portal is only available to Google Maps API for Work users.
Navigate to the "Resources" tab
Select the Resource called ["List of domains used by the Google Maps API Family."](https://na4.salesforce.com/a0Z60000000hXGe)
You should allow your applications to access these domains.

Please note that we do not recommend managing firewall restrictions by IP address, as the IPs associated with these domains are not static.